# Leaflet point along polyline at certain distance

Tags: javascript, leaflet, distance, polyline

I am trying to find the position along a poly line at a certain distance after the starting point.

For instance at 500m after the start, see sketch below:

[image]

Comment: I'd go for http://turfjs.org/docs/#along , even if that entails doing a `toGeoJson()` call from the Leaflet polyline layer.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks so much!!